# Running MVC 5 website without iis or visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a website using visual studio 2015 with MVC 5.
The website should run locally using local databse.
The problem is, I want to run this website as program, without need to install iis or visual studio to run it..

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is a website and not a program as such. It therefore requires IIS to run. You don't need Visual Studio however.

If you want a stand-alone executable, you need to use a different UI paradigm. Console, Winforms or Universal Windows App to name just three.

Comment: Well the website is already finished and ready to be published to customers, what should I do? I want them to have easy experience using my "program"..

Comment: I'm sorry to say that ASP.NET MVC 5 *requires* IIS to run. No ifs, no buts. You either need to run it in IIS or rewrite it using a desktop UI paradigm.

Comment: Alright, is there any way to keep iis always running on the customer computer? any way to keep things easier for them??

Comment: IIS is a Feature that can be added to any Windows system, and can be running all time.

Comment: I assume from the question that you have been using IIS Express to develop with. IIS is always running on a computer it is installed on. Setting up IIS and configuring your website is no easy task if you aren't experienced in doing so. IIS will not run on Windows Home in versions prior to Windows 10.

Comment: IIS Express, previously known as Cassini, is distributed with Visual Studio so that Windows Home can be used to develop Websites. It is mainly for students. Professionals don't use it unless they have servers to test the website in "Production mode"

Answer (score 1):

Your option is to migrate to dotnet Core which can host web application as a Windows service, or just a Console App. You dont need Visial Studio to host it at all.

Comment: Is it long process?

Comment: Depends on libraries you used, there is a tool to check compatibility

Comment: EF is supported but its a but different one. EF Core.

Comment: Mostly configs references etc, code should be fine, if you are nit using fancy 3rd party